# Open a custom URL using window.open() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.open

In Firefox 88 it seems that opening a custom deep-linking URL with `window.open(customURL, '_parent')` reloads the current tab? Is there any solution to this problem? Should I use an `<iframe>` instead of window.open()? The behavior is different in Chrome however.

**Required behaviour**: `window.open()` opens the deeplinking app while the web app (written in Angular) continues to work in the same frame.

Comment: Why are you specifying `_parent` as window name …?

Comment: @CBroe, here _parent is used to specify to open the window in the parent frame. Check Parameter Values this documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.

Comment: I know what the parameter _means_, I wanted to know where there are any frames involved in your setup in the first place, so that this becomes necessary in the first place, because your problem description didn’t mention anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

## Recommend an Iframe

Some browsers are particularly weary of `window.open` as its abused quite heavily and thus blocked. However, an `iframe` is pretty normal and if using an app scheme and supported, has the side-effect of opening up the app.

Here's an approach you could try.

```
function checkIsAppSupported(appSchemeUrl, msThreshold) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let docBlurOccurred = false

    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe', {
      src: appSchemeUrl,
      style: 'display:none'
    })
    document.appendChild(iframe)

    function onDocBlur() {
      docBlurOccurred = true
    }

    document.addEventListener('blur', onDocBlur)
    // or try the newer
    // document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', onDocBlur)

    setTimeout(() => {
      // cleanup
      iframe.remove()
      document.removeEventListener('blur', onDocBlur)
    
      resolve(docBlurOccurred)
    }, msThreshold); // checks if document focus changed within ms
  });
}

async function tryAppSupported() {
  const isAppSupported = await checkIsAppSupported('my-app://', 500);
  if (isAppSupported) {
    // do something
  }
}

tryAppSupported()
```

Meaning if the main window becomes out of focus near the time of iframe loading, you could reasonably assume the actual app scheme was loaded and moved focus off the current window.

There are some npms that do this type of thing for example
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-native-app and has great support for caring about what type of OS checks this behavior.

Happy coding.